# How can I use multiroot with matrix based functions in r

Tags: r, math

I have a function which must be called in a matrix form. I have tried using `multiroot` from package `rootSolve` to compute the roots but its not working at all. Is there a way I would redefine the function below or is there another alternative that is based on Newton-Raphson technique?

```
library(rootSolve)

  f <- function(q,m){
      c(F1 = 12 * ((exp(q[, 1]) * m[1])/(exp(q[, 1]) * m[1] + exp(q[, 2]) * m[2] + m[3])) - c(1,2),
        F2 = 12 * ((exp(q[, 2]) * m[2])/(exp(q[, 1]) * m[1] + exp(q[, 2]) * m[2] + m[3])) -c(3,3))
    }
    m = c(0.1,0.2,0.7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not have a solution. You can see that the numerators in the expressions of your function values are identical and always positive given the values for `m`.
So you are trying to solve `exp(q[, 1]) * m[1]=0)` and `exp(q[, 2]) * m[2]=0`.
That is not possible since `exp(...)` is always larger than zero.

If you try different starting values for `q` you will get different answers.

Comment: I just noticed it and I have edited it. But again the `exp` only covers `q's`. I mean `(exp(q[, 1])`. I hope this makes more sense after the correction

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in an outer function that performs the conversion.  Since the question was changed note that we use the original data shown in the Note at the end.

```
multiroot(function(q) f(t(q), m), c(1,1))
```

giving:

```
$root
[1] -14.67979 -14.67979

$f.root
          F1           F2 
5.618059e-06 1.123612e-06 

$iter
[1] 13

$estim.precis
[1] 3.370836e-06
```

### Note

f and m are assumed to be:

library(rootSolve)

```
f <- function(q,m){
  c(F1 = 12 * ((exp(q[, 1]) * m[1])/(exp(q[, 1]) * m[1] + exp(q[, 2]) * m[2] + m[3])),
    F2 = 12 * ((exp(q[, 2]) * m[2])/(exp(q[, 1]) * m[1] + exp(q[, 2]) * m[2] + m[3])))
}
m = c(1,0.2,0.9)
```

Comment: what does `t()` do? I thought it might be doing the transpose but I don't get my expected results. I expect `-0.1335314, 0.6931472` From the first function and `0.2719337, 0.4054651` from the second function. But I also notice that I get something similar to these when `c(1,2)` from the first function is replace with `c(1,3)`. With the second function `c(3,3)` being replaced by `c(2,3)`. Clearly some transpose.

Comment: `t(x)` is the transpose of `x`. For a plain vector it is the same as `matrix(x, 1)`. Note that `multiroot(function(q) f(t(q), m), c(1,1))$f.root`, is `c(0, 0)` to 6 digits using `f` and `m` from the question. You are not going to get exactly zero as explained in the other answer, i.e. the ratio of two positive numbers cannot be zero, and also even if the solution existed the solution can only be expected up to numeric approximation.

Comment: I actually edited the question but as soon as I did that I received an error. My expected solution for `q` is `q <- matrix(c(-0.1335314,0.6931472,0.2719337,0.4054651), nrow=2)` But when I ran the code as it is I get `Error in stode(y, times, func, parms = parms, ...) ` but without the transpose I get `Error in q[, 1]incorrect number of dimensions`. What could be the problem?

Comment: another thing I realized from your explanation. `q` is a matrix and getting its transpose changes everything. If it was a vector there wouldn't be any problem.

Comment: If you change the problem then you need to change the answer to correspond.  If f and m are as in the revised question and q is the matrix shown in your comment then  use `multiroot(function(q) f(matrix(q, 2),m), q)`